# How to create TEMPORARY table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

how to create a TEMPORARY table in laravel, insert a record and retrieve
hello, I'm trying to create a temp table in laravel and insert a record and retrieve that record from temp table and then drop the table.

But my temp table is not created

```
DB::raw(“CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_temp(temp_id VARCHAR(100),tempcolumn1 VARCHAR(100),tempcolumn2 VARCHAR(100),tempcolumn3 VARCHAR(100)) ;
```

Answer (score -7, accepted):

With Schema you can create temp tables...

```
 Schema::create('temp', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('session_id');

            });
```

Comment: The method [temporary()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_temporary) could be used: `$table->temporary();`...

Comment: this answer does not create a temporary table.

Comment: It is just a normal table with `tmp` name !!!
Or you should add this `$table->temporary();` in the creation

Answer (score 14):

Try this

// CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

```
$productList = DB::insert( DB::raw( "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempproducts") );
```

// DELETE TEMPORARY TABLE

```
$dropTable = DB::unprepared( DB::raw( "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempproducts" ) );
```

Comment: I'd suggest using DB::statement()

Comment: @feskr You were right its better to use DB::statement("create temporary table x")

Answer (score 2):

I have recently created a temp table( laravel 8) as such:

```
public function createLocalStoreProductTable(): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        $tempTable = env("DB_TEMP_STORE_PRODUCT_TABLE_NAME");
        DB::connection('mysql')->statement(
            "CREATE TABLE " . $tempTable . " (
                    `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `store_uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)
                     PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
                     KEY `store_uid` (`store_uid`)
                     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3035849 DEFAULT 
                       CHARSET=utf8;"

 return response()->json(array('success' => true), Response::HTTP_OK);
```

Comment: Please explain how is this temp table ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a temporary table containing the result of a query:

```
DB::statement('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE your_table_name SELECT ...insert query here');
```

If you want to define the table before inserting rows:

```
DB::statement('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE your_table_name (...insert normal DDL here)');
```

Then just insert rows as in a normal table:

```
DB::table('your_table_name')->insert(["column" => "value"]);
```

or get result as in normal table:

```
DB::table('your_table_name')->get();
```